# An unusual Union

Tags: riddle, wordplay

We both wear a wedding ring,
I wear mine on the left hand and you wear yours on the right.

We appear to look at each other,
But I know it's only I that really sees you as I look deeply into your eyes.

We are married to each other,
Yet, I am not dependent upon you even though you cannot exist without me.

**What are you to me, if not my spouse?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> My mirror image.

We both wear a wedding ring,
I wear mine on the left hand and you wear yours on the right.

> In the mirror, the sides are reversed.

We appear to look at each other,
But I know it's only I that really sees you as I look deeply into your eyes.

> The mirror image seems to be looking back, but it doesn't actually see anything.

We are married to each other,
Yet, I am not dependent upon you even though you can not exist with out me.

> A mirror image cannot exist without the person, but the person is not dependent on it in any way.